# Чи варто в українській мові вживати слово "даний"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Чарівне слово "даний" є канцеляризмом, стверджують на сайті [pustunchik.ua](https://pustunchik.ua/ua/online-school/linguistics/ob-upotreblenii-slova-dannyy-v-ukrainskom-yazyke):

> Мабуть, Тобі часто доводиться чути (або й вживати) такі словосполучення:
>
> - на даний момент;
> - у даній ситуації;
> - дана стаття;
> - даний договір.
>
> Здається, ніби слово «даний» робить висловлювання офіційнішим, переконливішим. Та насправді воно — канцеляризм, якого варто уникати.

Однак інтенсивно використовується в діловодстві. Чи буде помилкою, якщо вживати це слово у розмові чи на письмі?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Канцеляризми, до яких і відноситься слово *даний* — це не ті слова, вживання яких є помилкою, а стилістично марковані слова, які доречно використовувати у відповідних текстах. В юридичних, наукових документах, статтях вони природні. В розмовній мові їх використання надаватиме офіційного забарвлення і звучатиме дещо комічно. Приклад — возний Тетерваковський з «Наталки-Полтавки».

Тобто слово *даний* можете використовувати в офіційному, юридичному, науковому і діловому мовленні, зокрема при письмових типах цього мовлення. В розмовному — також, якщо враження від використання <strike>даного</strike> цього слова вас влаштовує.

Посилання: [Вікіпедія: Канцеляризми (кеш)](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:QmQwZN0NCakJ:https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Answer (score 3):

Додам до [відповіді Oksana Çeliker](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2996), що не в кожному значенні «даний» є канцеляризмом.

«Даний» має два значення:

1. Пасивний дієприкметник до «дати».
2. Канцеляристський еквівалент для «цей».

От у першому значенні «даний» не є канцеляризмом, хоча може використовуватися і в офіційному контексті:

- «…на своїй, Богом даній землі…»
- «…даною мені владою…».

Друге значення, мабуть, походить від першого. Наприклад, при вирішенні геометричної задачі словосполучення «даний трикутник» можна сприймати і як канцеляристський вираз для «цей прикутник», так і як «трикутник, даний (заданий) в умові задачі (автором задачі)» (нагадаю, що умова задач часто розділяється на дві секції: «дано» і «що треба відшукати/довести/обчислити»). Я припускаю, що саме так і виникло друге канцелярське значення — спочатку «даний» використовували до чогось, явно кимось даного, потім для неявно (за)даного, а потім і як синонім до «цей».

Отже на мою думку критерій такий: чим легше ми можемо сказати, ким саме щось було дано в конкретному випадку вжитку слова «даний» — тим у меншій мірі воно в тому випадку є канцеляризмом. Якщо ж «даний» використовується для чогось, що було щойно введено в контекст самим автором тексту — то же майже напевно канцеляризм.